# Capture java app traffic with fiddler

Tags: java, eclipse, fiddler, network-traffic

I know this question has been asked and answered a lot of times but I really need a little help with my application.
First of all I am trying to capture traffic from an existing java app (I don't have the source code to modify it).
What I did so far :

- I have exported the root certificate from tools-->Options-->Actions
- I have run \bin\keytool.exe -import -file C:\Users\\Desktop\FiddlerRoot.cer
  -keystore FiddlerKeystore -alias Fiddler
- I download Eclipse and run the java app from run-->External tools-->external Tools Configuration and put as location:JDK_HOME\bin\java.exe and working directory my app_dir
- I put as arguments :

  -DproxySet=true
  -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1
  -DproxyPort=8888
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=app_dir\FiddlerKeystore
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=key
  -jar app.jar

I still can't capture any traffic from fiddler.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question is not at all clear. It states *"I still can capture any trffic from fiddler"* so what is the problem, or does this text omit a negation? Please read about and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AdrianHHH you are right.I meant  I can't capture any traffic

Comment: Have you tried to enable the settings "Act as system proxy at startup"? Some Java apps respect the Windows proxy settings.